# Ember template displayed twice

Tags: templates, ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-old-router

There is a simple ember.js app with one view displayed in a particular place on the webpage. Have a look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jkkK3/9/

```
App = Ember.Application.create({

  ready: function(){
      this._super();
      this.ApplicationView.create().appendTo(".content");
  },

  ApplicationController: Ember.Controller.extend({
  }),

  ApplicationView: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application'
  }),

  Router: Ember.Router.extend({
    root: Ember.Route.extend({  
    })
  })
});
```

My question is: Why is the "some content here" element displayed twice? It works when I remove the router, but that's exactly what I cannot do, since I try to add Router to my Ember app. Could you please help me to display application view only once, inside the red box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using router, applicationController/view are used by default. In your ready method you append it explicitly. So 'application' template is appended twice. Remove appending it in ready method and it will be appended only once.

By default it's appended to body but if you want to override use rootElement property of Ember.Application

```
Ember.Application.create( {
    rootElement : '.content',
    ....
})
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. So how can I display it only once, append it to the ".content" div?

Comment: Then it is placed in the body element. I need to put it inside specific element, ".content" in my example.

Comment: Define rootElement : '.content'. See it here - http://jsfiddle.net/jkkK3/13/. Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow and my answers aren't full sometimes

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. I just looked for this in the wrong place - in the view. You saved my day!